# Keep app from opening when clicking a link

Tags: settings, 7.1-nougat, hyperlinks, 8.0-oreo

I forget what setting I've turned on, or when, but whenever I click a link to the New York Times website, it opens the New York Times app. I don't want it to do that. I could remove the NYT app, but I want to keep it. (I find it useful.)

Is there a way to change this behavior? Even better, get Android to ask me which I want when I click the link. Changing the default web browser is not desired.

This is in both Nougat and Oreo®.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Settings → Apps → NYTimes → Open by default:

- *Open Supported Links*: set it to *Ask every time*
- tap *Clear Defaults*

Tested on Android 6.0.1 and Android 7.1.2.

In Android 8 (Oreo®) you can also reach that setting via:

- Settings → Apps & Notifications → (Advanced) → Default Apps → Opening links

You can alternatively stop using Chrome since Firefox, for example, does not let you choose an app to open such links (if I'm correct).

Comment: Settings path for 7 is essentially the same as 6. 8 seems to add a new path, although the old one works too.

Answer (score -2):

Check your browser's permissions and stop it from launching other apps if it can.
Try clicking on the link from another browser.
Check NYT app permissions to see if it can behave like that.